# Collaborative webmapping systems/platforms

Tags: web-mapping, ushahidi, crowdsourcing

What are the existing collaborative webmapping systems/platforms?

I am looking for some information like on [this page for wiki softwares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wiki_software), but specific to out-of-the-box on-line geographical data capture systems.

These systems should not necessarily be open-source but should remain highly customisable for specific purposes. I am specifically interested in systems that could be made private, with a capture tool usable on mobile devices.

So far, I am aware of the systems [Ushahidi](http://www.ushahidi.com/products/ushahidi-platform) and [LocalWiki](http://localwiki.org/). I am sure you know others!

**Precision**: I am not looking for existing collaborative cartography projects like in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24663/) but rather in the background systems for these projects. Wikipedia's system for example has been released as the MediWiki system - maybe there are comparable initiatives in collaborative webmapping.

Answer (score 2):

[geojson.io](http://geojson.io/) is very simple Collaborative webmapping platform, it's open source, so you can customize it.

Comment: Very interesting! and the code is available from https://github.com/mapbox/geojson.io